How can I best install a PVC p-trap on 1-5/8" metal pipe?
I’ve got an old metal drain pipe in the basement and the p-trap is entirely corroded. The top part is still stuck and I could use my disc cutter to take it off, but then I’m left with a 1 5/8 metal pipe that needs a new p-trap.
PVC just seems a lot more sensible (no corrosion, easy to swap out), but I’m wondering how I can best go from that 1 5/8 pipe to a pvc p-trap. I’m just asking because I’ve been looking for pipe fittings for 1 5/8 to smaller, but no luck, almost as if 1 5/8 is a non-standard size.
Any recommendations?

Are you measuring the outside diameter or the inside diameter?  Pipe size is the inside diameter.

In short, just use a rubber no-hub (Fernco) coupler. This is a no-pressure scenario and it'll work just fine.
